# Proper Use of Mailer in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a form to contact me via email on my site. I was going to create s StaticPages controller and use that to show the view for my contact form. However, I don't know how I would manage sending the emails unless I had a dedicated controller for my contact form.

What is the proper design to implement a way to have an email sent to me through a form in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a single controller for the contact form, and no ActiveRecord model.

You may wish to read the [Rails Guide on ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for how to create an ActionMailer model.

Answer (score 0):

Have a ContactForm controller. Have it display the form, have another method to call your ActionMailer deliver() method.